# Zimbra Imap Proxy

Tags: nginx, zimbra

Recently upgraded from Zimbra 8.6.0 to 8.8.15.  Now the IMAP and POP ports aren't proxying correctly.  (or at all).  If I log in to the server and 
telnet localhost 7143 it connects.  If I telnet localhost 143, I receive connection refused.  I've checked every proxy setting multiple times and it just continues to give the error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try rewrite all configs trough Zimbra CLI?

Comment: Yes.  Tried reproducing all configs through command line.  Verified configs and they appear to be correct.